# Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.bootstrap-servers' in string value "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, properties

I have to continue a projet of someone else, but I when I run the spring application on Intellij, I'm facing an error. I'm new in spring and maven.
I have a application.properties in the ressource folder, there isn't any xml file for configuration.

Here is the build part **pom.xml** :

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <!--
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>kobdig.SimulationApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</code>
```

**SimulationApplication.java** :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimulationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(SimulationApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**SenderConfig.java** :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "file:application.properties")
public class SenderConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }
```

**application.properties** :

```
server.port=9090
kafka.bootstrap-servers = localhost:2020
```

and **Sender.java**:

```
public class Sender {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(String topic, String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}' to topic='{}'", payload, topic);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);
    }
}
```

I'm facing this error :

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder 'kafka.bootstrap-servers' in string value
>   "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}"

Already tried many things, I saw many similar topics on stackOverflow but can't find the problem.
@PropertySource doesn't helped.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces? kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:2020

Comment: Yes not the solution :(

Comment: Did the server port properties work?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the port 2020 to 9092 which is the port of my kafka server, but the error is still here, so I think it commes from the code itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your application.properties file is in your class path .If you property file is in another package then it will not be taken up automatically by spring.

Try using property source like below, if the property file is in your classpath

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

If you place the application.properties under `src/main/resources` then there is no need to use the `@PropertySource` annotation.Spring should automatically take it up.

Verify that other values from your `application.properties` are getting picked up, if not it might be because of the bean `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, try creating a bean of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: Thank you ! I added application.properties in the classpath with intellij, it worked for the application, but when I run with maven the error is still here, do you have a solution in my case ?

Comment: Where did you place your application.properties file . You will have to rebuild the project using maven and then start the server for the changes to be reflected.